# Syntax error while running the c program despite having no problem during compiling

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, syntax-error

### I am trying to run a basic program 'hello world'using this code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{ 
 printf("hello world\n");
 return 0;
}
```

---

There is no error while compiling but when i try to run the code the error is:

---

```
./hello.c: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token'('
./hello.c: line 2: 'int main()'
```

---

How can i solve this because ive tried everything and i dont think there is a syntax error.

Comment: Welcome to SO. There can never be a syntax error if you run your compiled binary. I would assume you run your source code on bash instead of the compiled binary.

Comment: How _exactly_ do you attempt to run your program?

Comment: Please show how you run your program. Hint: The binary should not contain a `.c` in filename

Comment: First make an `executable` using `gcc -o filename filename.c` then execute it using `$./filename`.

Comment: Alternative: install [TCC](https://bellard.org/tcc/), add `#!/usr/local/bin/tcc -run` (or similar depending on your setup) to the top of your .c file and make it executable (if it isn't already)

Comment: @pmg Sure, but tcc is a bit out of date.

Answer (score 3):

You don't run the `.c` file from the shell. After you compile the program, you run the executable that was created.

So if you compiled it like:

```
gcc -o hello hello.c
```

Then you run it with

```
./hello
```

When you use `./hello.c`, the shell tries to run your C source code as a shell script. That won't work because they're completely different languages.